# Pinescript V5 error: The 'timeframe' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a script that I am trying to plot an X where the 2 mA's cross with line.new
I have tried the line.new in another script and it seems to work so I am at a loss as to why is does not work in this script. I am just setting the y but getting the error.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="My MACD with crosses", shorttitle="My MACD", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

// Get User Input
i_showCross = input.bool(title="Show MA Crossovers", defval=true)

// Calculate MA's using user input selections
fast_ma = i_sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(i_src, i_fast_length) : ta.ema(i_src, i_fast_length)
slow_ma = i_sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(i_src, i_slow_length) : ta.ema(i_src, i_slow_length)

crossOver = ta.crossover(fast_ma, slow_ma)
crossUnder = ta.crossunder(slow_ma, fast_ma)

// show label
crossX = label.new(bar_index, na, str.tostring(fast_ma) + "crossed under " + str.tostring(slow_ma), style=label.style_xcross, size=size.small, color=color.red, textcolor=color.red)
    label.set_y(crossX,slow_ma)
```

Answer (score 6):

Read the error message carefully.

> The 'timeframe' argument is incompatible with functions that have side
> effects

The `timeframe` argument is in your `indicator()` call so you shouldn't be looking at somewhere else.

If you don't need to change the timeframe, just remove `timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true` from your `indicator()` call.

So it should be:

```
indicator(title="My MACD with crosses", shorttitle="My MACD")
```

If you need multi timeframe analysis, you should use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function.